No stdout using a venv with a gui interface
I have a python script that reads a file that represent some parameters from a system (temperature, pressure...). I am trying to create a visual interface that enables a user to start this script using a button and get an output of the values checked.
Here is the gui script : (I'm using PySide6, it's only part of it but it's functionnal for testing)
#!./venv/bin/python3

import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QProcess
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                               QGridLayout,
                               QGroupBox,
                               QLabel,
                               QMainWindow,
                               QPushButton,
                               QTextEdit,
                               QWidget)

def main():
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setWindowTitle('Watchdog')

            self.pReceiverNn = None

            ##############
            # Nn Antenna #
            ##############
            self.receiverNnLabel = QLabel('Receiver monitoring')
            self.startReceiverNnButton = QPushButton('Start')
            self.startReceiverNnButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')
            self.startReceiverNnButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.start_receiver('nn'))
            self.stopReceiverNnButton = QPushButton('Stop')
            self.stopReceiverNnButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stop_receiver('nn'))

            # Nn Box Layout
            self.nnLayout = QGridLayout()
            self.nnLayout.addWidget(self.receiverNnLabel, 0, 0)
            self.nnLayout.addWidget(self.startReceiverNnButton, 0, 1)
            self.nnLayout.addWidget(self.stopReceiverNnButton, 0, 2)

            # Final Nn box
            self.nnBox = QGroupBox('Nn Antenna')
            self.nnBox.setLayout(self.nnLayout)

            ################
            # Error output #
            ################
            self.outputNn = QTextEdit()

            ###############
            # FINAL LAYOUT#
            ###############
            finalLayout = QGridLayout()
            finalLayout.addWidget(self.nnBox, 0, 0)
            finalLayout.addWidget(self.outputNn, 1, 0)

            widget = QWidget()
            widget.setLayout(finalLayout)
            self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        ############
        # FUNCTIONS#
        ############
        ## Receiver Watchdog functions
        def start_receiver(self, ant):
            match ant:
                case 'nn':
                    if self.pReceiverNn is None:
                        self.pReceiverNn = QProcess()
                        self.pReceiverNn.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout_nn_receiver)
                        self.pReceiverNn.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.receiver_nn_finished)
                        self.pReceiverNn.finished.connect(self.receiver_nn_finished)
                        self.pReceiverNn.start('python3', ['nn_receiver_check.py'])
                        self.startReceiverNnButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
                        self.outputNn.append('Nn receiver watchdog started')
                case 'ns':
                    pass

        def stop_receiver(self, ant):
            match ant:
                case 'nn':
                    if self.pReceiverNn:
                        self.pReceiverNn.terminate()
                        self.pReceiverNn = None
                        self.startReceiverNnButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')
                case 'ns':
                    pass

        def handle_stdout_nn_receiver(self):
            txt = self.pReceiverNn.readAllStandardOutput()
            txt = bytes(txt).decode('utf8')
            self.outputNn.append(txt)

        def receiver_nn_finished(self):
            self.outputNn.append('Nn servos watchdog stopped')
            self.startReceiverNnButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')
            self.pReceiverNn = None

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


And here is the script to read the files with the stdout, nn_receiver_check.py :
import sys
import time

from datetime import datetime

def main():
    while 1:

        #####
        # Here check the file and store the data
        #####

        # Compare the data to a threshold value and do a stdout if the value is not okay
        n = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
        sys.stdout.write(f'The test at {n} was not okay')

        time.sleep(300)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


The aim is to update the output window in the gui with what comes from the stdout.
I'm coding with PyCharm and when I try the code there, it works without any issues.
But when I try to start the code in command line after making the script executable :
chmod +x gui.py,
./gui.py
The gui starts, I can click the button and see in the output that the subprocess started but then I get nothing from the stdout.
Could there be an issue regarding the venv ?

First of all, do you really need to start the other script as a completely separate python process? If you actually need a separate process for CPU needs, then consider using multiprocessing instead, if the reading may be blocking (or really requires an internal loop), then use threading (possibly with QThread), if it doesn't block and you just need to call it at regular intervals, use QTimer. In any case, python output is buffered by default, use the -u flag (but you should also flush the stdout). Finally, move the class definition outside main() as it's pointless to have it there.

I put only one script in the example here but in the app there is 6 differents scripts similar to this one and they need to be started separately (we must be able to start some of them without the other). The idea was to have the 1-6 different processes running at the same time, but I will have a look at QTimer instead of using the sleep() inside the secondary script.
Thank you for the advice about the class definition, I'm kind of new to using if name == 'main'.

Please, first extract a [mcve]. Also, there are ways to make mistakes in the context of venvs, so include precise steps you're taking as well.

Sorry, in my mind it was already a small part of my code for testing. I managed to solve my issue by using stdout.flush(). Thank you @musicamante
